# How to change Dimensions of an SwiftUI Default Button on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, button, swiftui

I want to change the behaviour of an SwiftUI Button so that two of them automatic get the same size.

But somehow I always only affect an ParentView of my View.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("ABC", action: {return}).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.green)
            Button("EFCHHSJFJSJDNJS", action: {return}).buttonStyle(MorePaddingButtonStyle()).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.yellow)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

And it should be sized like this:

[image: Mockup]

The example is located [here](https://github.com/jawil003/SwiftUIButtonExampleIssueSameSize) in an GitHub repo.

Hope someone can help me to resize them with their background/shape (most likely for the default Button).

Comment: Can you please add an image for the expected result?

Comment: Sure I will make an mockup of some kind. At least I want both to have an equal size so that they take 50% each or the smaller one has the same width as the large one.

Answer (score 0):

Use button with label

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { print("ABC") }) {
                Text("ABC").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).background(Color.green)
            
            Button(action: { print("EFCHHSJFJSJDNJS") }) {
                Text("EFCHHSJFJSJDNJS").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }.buttonStyle(MorePaddingButtonStyle()).background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

The default button style can not set the width. It automatically set the width according to the button contains. So use PlayStyle or your own MorePaddingButtonStyle.